# Reverse a string from a file in c++ using vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector, char, reverse

I'm trying to write a program that reads a text from a file (only strings) and reverse it. The following code does that, but it doesn't take into account spaces between words:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>


using namespace std; 

int main(){

    ifstream file("file.txt");
    char i;
    int x;
    vector<char> vec;

    if(file.fail()){
        cerr<<"error"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }



    while(file>>i){
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

    x=vec.size(); 

    reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    for(int y=0; y<x; y++){
        cout<<vec[y];
    }


    return 0;
}
```

If the text on the file is "dlroW olleH", the program would print out "HelloWorld". What can I do so that it prints "Hello World" (with the space between both words)?

Comment: Read the input using std::getline.

Comment: `>>` default behaviour is to treat whitespace as unwanted and discard it for you. Usually very helpful. Not so helpful in this case, though.

Comment: is your code running without `#include<algorithm>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user4581301 pointed out, `>>` will automatically skip any whitespace. You can disable this by using the [`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) stream manipulator and changing `file>>i` to `file>>std::noskipws>>i`. A better solution altogether is to simply use `std::getline` to read the whole string into an `std::string`, reverse it, and print it out instead handling the characters individually.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("input.txt");
    //insert error checking stuff here
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);
    //insert error checking stuff here
    std::reverse(line.begin(), line.end());
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

Just a note about your code, you should declare variables only when they are used. For example, your variable `x` is only used at the end of the program, but it is declared all the way at the top. `using namespace std` can also be [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/9254539).

Answer (score 2):

The `reverse` function is working perfectly fine, the problem lies here:

```
while(file>>i){
```

`std::operator>>` skips spaces and new lines, you will need to use `std::istream::getline` to avoid this or try `std::noskipws` manipulator.

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::skipws, std::noskipws
#include <sstream>      // std::istringstream

int main () {
  char a, b, c;

  std::istringstream iss ("  123");
  iss >> std::skipws >> a >> b >> c;
  std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';

  iss.seekg(0);
  iss >> std::noskipws >> a >> b >> c;
  std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123
  1
```